# Why getting .indexOf() return as -1, although element exists in the array?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

"addresses" is an array of objects, each object element is having specific _id.
I'm trying to find **.indexOf(req.params.a_id)** within idsArray (which is an array of ids of all those object elements within the array), but **.indexOf() returns -1** although _id exists in idsArray.

[code snapshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njhQg.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Please include actual code in a [mcve] and not a picture of code

Comment: Please submit the a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, not just a screenshot of the code. In trying to replicate it you might end up finding what the issue is. It's possible that you are trying to compare two different types or something.

Comment: My first thought is that you're looking in the `addresses` Array for an array element whose value is equal to the value held in the `req.params.a_id` property.

Comment: These are not your own objects are they, you are using Mongoose or something similar. The _id field is essentially not a string, it is an object that has a .toString() method which prints an id, so you are looking through a list of objects whichis not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think .indexOf is most used in strings, you can get it by this way :

```
idsArray.filter(x => x.id == req.params.a_id)
```

this will return an array with the matching element.

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

UPDATE:
to find the index you can use

```
idsArray.findIndex(x=> x == req.params.a_id)
```

Comment: Does `idsArray` hold objects that have an `id` property?

Comment: in my example yes.
idsArray = [{id:1, name: 'Freddy'}, {id:2, name: 'Ethan'}]
you can filter by any other property

Comment: How do you know that? There is nothing to suggest that at all. In fact, according to the code screenshot, that's very much untrue, as the array is created by mapping over another array to get the IDs of objects. EDIT: WHERE DID YOU GET THAT ARRAY FROM?!

Comment: I don't know what objets idsArray contains, I just gave him an example if idsArray is an array like this [{id:1, name: 'Freddy'}, {id:2, name: 'Ethan'}] so my approach is right, if idsArray is an array like this [1,2,3,4] the approach will be idsArray.filter(x => x == req.params.a_id)

Comment: addresses array is an array of objects, and every object element contains unique `_id` property, I'm just extracting these _ids from every object element and stores it inside `idsArray` so that i can find indexOf one of the `_id` that comes from `req.params.a_id`

Comment: ok so I guess your idsArray looks like this [1,2,3,4, 32,92, 53] if it is the case you can do idsArray.filter(x => x == req.params.a_id) will return an array with id, then you need you validate the length

Comment: .filter() will return array of id, if it finds inside idsArray (i.e x == req.params.a_id) else an empty array, but i need index of that element if it exists inside the array.

Comment: @ShashankYadav I just updated the solution according your last comment

Comment: Now its working fine, but still wondering why I'm not getting expected result with .indexOf(). Anyways Thanks! @JoseRodriguez

Comment: please mark this solution as good

Answer (score 1):

To check if an element exists in an array you can use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
idsArray.some(id => id === req.params.a_id)
```

which returns `true` or `false` if the id exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check type of your variables.
Maybe req.params.a_id is string ("1") in your case?